# Suggest alternate approach to read Token from Email for Automated Testing (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, automation, gmail-api

I am currently working for an application that deals with a lot of secure data. On every login operation, I need to enter the registered Email after which I need to enter a 6-digit Token that is sent to my email.

I do understand and have worked with both **Gmail API** and **JavaMail API** to automate the above mentioned scenario where my test script when executed enters the valid/registered Email then fetches the token and logs me in the application. Please do make a note that each time the Token is generated, the token expires in 15 minutes and the token can only be used only once.

The above is the scenario where I am looking for an alternate approach, rather than using Gmail/JavaMail API where I can read the mail, fetch the token and use the same to run the test case. The reason I am looking for an alternate approach is that, the test script will be used to validate for the same test multiple times, I guess 1000 times a day.

The application has authentication of 2 ways, one where the user receives and email and the other form of authentication is by using Authy/Google Authy app to login. **I am only looking for suggestions/pointers with respect to Email Token verification method.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once I need take verification code from a SMS. I can't access to the mobile phone, and I try yo read from the application logs. Maybe the application which generate the code have any logs you could review to take the code.

Comment: SMS? I have mentioned that I need something alternative with respect to the Email Token Verification.

Comment: Maybe I don't express so well, sorry. My option was, go into the Token Verification generator log, and search into the log file, the code. It is not an alternative, is an option to take the code and could continue with your automation.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same type of logic in our application and I solved it by just calling the Authentication api directly and storing the key in my Testcontext.
Obviously there is some code that gets the key, puts it in the email and sends it out. You should try to call that code directly if possible.